# A conditional test within a return statement

Tags: c++

what is the meaning of: `return _a != MAX_A_VAL` ?  I've not seen conditionals in a return statement beyond ternary operators.  What's this? By the way, this was used in an `operator bool()` class method.

Comment: Since you've already received three answers, all of them good, I'm not going to give yet another. Suppose you saw return statement that returns a computed value such as `return a+b*c;` No complaints, right? This is just a different kind of expression, a boolean expression. It's still just an expression, just like `a+b*c`.

Comment: You have three good answers to your question. You need to pick one as the correct answer. It's the lifeblood of this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means do the comparsion `_a != MAX_A_VAL`, and then return its result (`true` or `false`)

Answer (score 3):

It means that if `_a` is NOT equal to `MAX_A_VAL` it should return `true` and otherwise it should return `false`

It's a boolean comparision.

It may be easier to read like so:

```
return (_a != MAX_A_VAL);
```

or another way you could look at it is:

```
bool retvalue = (_a != MAX_A_VAL);
return retvalue;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement can use *any* expression as its return value, it doesn't have to be a simple one like a variable.

Comment: So it is returning the result of the test? Duh!